# Trying to open a storyboard from monotouch is giving me an error

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, xcode-storyboard

I have created a masterdetail storyboard application within monotouch. When I try double clicking on the storyboard to open it up in xcode I get an error

> Error updating Xcode project`. Could not generate outlet 'DetailItem' in class 'LCMasterDetail.DetailViewController' as its type 'System.String' could not be resolved to Obj-C.

```
MonoDevelop.MacDev.ObjCIntegration.ObjectiveCGenerationException: Could not generate     outlet' DetailItem' in class 'LCMasterDetail.DetailViewController' as its type 'System.String' could not be resolved to Obj-C
at MonoDevelop.MacDev.ObjCIntegration.NSObjectTypeInfo.GenerateObjcType (System.String   directory, System.String[] frameworks) [0x001e8] in  /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.MacDev/ObjCIntegration/NSObjectTypeInfo.cs:159 
at MonoDevelop.MacDev.XcodeSyncing.XcodeSyncedType.SyncOut (MonoDevelop.MacDev.XcodeSyncing.XcodeSyncContext context) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.MacDev/XcodeSyncing/XcodeSyncedType.cs:64 
at MonoDevelop.MacDev.XcodeSyncing.XcodeMonitor.UpdateProject (IProgressMonitor monitor, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 allItems, MonoDevelop.MacDev.XcodeIntegration.XcodeProject emptyProject) [0x00324] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.MacDev/XcodeSyncing/XcodeMonitor.cs:137 
at MonoDevelop.MacDev.XcodeSyncing.XcodeProjectTracker.UpdateXcodeProject (IProgressMonitor monitor) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.MacDev/XcodeSyncing/XcodeProjectTracker.cs:315
```

Been a newbie noob to monotouch I have no clue whats wrong.

Anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of MonoDevelop are you using? This works just fine with MonoDevelop 2.8.5, the latest stable release. If you're using the 2.9.x beta series, would be able able to try with 2.8.5? Also, what version of Mono do you have installed?

The above information can be found by clicking on 'MonoDevelop -> About -> Version Information'.

EDIT: This is a regression in the 2.9.x beta series, so if you just switch to the stable version everything will work as expected.

Comment: I have also fixed this regression so things will work correctly with the next release of the 2.9 beta series. Also, just to make it clear, the 2.8 stable series is not affected by this.

Comment: Thanks Alan. Yes I was running the non stable version

Comment: I'm still getting an error in 2.8.8.4 System.Exception: Did not get project info
  at MonoDevelop.MacDev.XcodeSyncing.XcodeProjectTracker.UpdateTypes (IProgressMonitor monitor) [0x00029] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-mac-2.8.8.4/cc9fe83c/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.MacDev/XcodeSyncing/XcodeProjectTracker.cs:374